Page resources shows N/A
My page resources shows N/A after crawl in Search console.
Please see the screenshot, also my sitemap shows
No referring sitemaps detected
Please see the screenshot for all issues


Have you actually submitted a sitemap, and is the page you're inspecting listed in it?

Yes, I have submitted the site map in that the Index page is listed.
Also later, the condition changed to crawled but no images not loaded
